# Error while installing apt,apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

While I am going to install any application by the command sudo apt-get install   I get the error apt-get not install , while I tried to install apt-get by adding repo of wget I get  404 not found, while I tried to install it by apt by running the command sudo apt install apt-get , I see this error 
/usr/bin/apt: 1: /usr/bin/apt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
so by no means I am able to install anything
please anybody can help me to solve this issue that I am facing, it will be helpfull

Comment: Your question is not clear, especially "while I tried to install apt-get by adding repo of wget I get  404 not found' part. Please edit it and make it little meaningful.

Comment: Apt is already installed on every flavor and release of Ubuntu (with a single exception). If you happened to install that single exception, then the easy fix is obvious - install any other .iso of Ubuntu. If you had apt installed but unwisely removed it, then your system might be recoverable...but the effort involved may not be worthwhile.

Comment: Please at least add screenshots of your problem.